# How to execute a bitcode file with LLVM 3.3?

Tags: llvm

I'm starting to program with LLVM, and trying to execute a bitcode.
I came up to this code, adapted from old examples (my doubt is in the creation of the `MemoryBuffer`, `getFile(string)` does not exist anymore):

```
    string *errorString = new string;
    LLVMContext context;

    OwningPtr<MemoryBuffer> *mb = new OwningPtr<MemoryBuffer>;
    MemoryBuffer::getFileOrSTDIN(argv[1], *mb);
    Module *m = ParseBitcodeFile(mb->take(), context, errorString);
    ExecutionEngine *ee = EngineBuilder(m).create();

    Function *main = m->getFunction("main");
```

From this line on nothing works (segmentation fault)

1 - "standard" approach?

```
    void * f = ee->getPointerToFunction(main);
    void (*FP)() = (void (*)()) f;
```

2 - lli's approach, not sure about the '0' for envp

```
    vector<string> *argList = new vector<string>;
    ee->runFunctionAsMain(main, *argList, 0);
```

3 - a generalization of 2.

```
    vector<struct GenericValue> *argList = new vector<struct GenericValue>;
    ee->runFunction(main, *argList);
```

Comment: BTW, you might want to use [`ParseIRFile()` from IRReader.h](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm.html#a52a8eb337079367476011bcc10088969), it wraps up all the memory buffer stuff and gives you a straightforward "give me filename, get a `Module`" interface.

Comment: Thank you very much, now the code is cleaner, but I'm still getting "Segmentation fault" trying to execute `main`.

Comment: Have you verified "main" is indeed there? You can use `m->getFunctionList()` and `->dump()` each function there to verify.

Comment: Yes, `Function *main = m->getFunction("main");main->dump();` prints the correct IR.

Answer (score 1):

The `lli` tool is your reference here. As an official LLVM tool and part of the repository and releases, it is always up to date with the latest LLVM APIs. The file `tools/lli/lli.cpp` is just ~500 lines of code, much of it header files, option definitions and comments. The `main` function contains the exact flow of execution and is cleanly structured and commented.

You can pick one of two approaches:

1. Start with `lli.cpp` as is, gradually stripping things you don't need.
2. Take the relevant parts from `lli.cpp` into your own main file.

---

If the problem is rather with your `main`, you can always find examples of bitcode files that actually run with `lli` within the LLVM tests - `test/ExecutionEngine` - most tests there are bitcode files on which `lli` is invoked and runs successfully.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, I am reading lli.cpp, and following it in my code (point 2 above), but still functions like `getPointerToFunction` and `runFunctionAsMain` cause a segmentation fault. As I said before, `dump()` prints the correct IR code for the function, so this is not a parsing problem.

Comment: @luomoradioattivo: so there may be a problem with your IR. Can your code run successfully one of the tests I pointed at? If yes, the problem is with your IR, if not then it's with the C++ driver.

Comment: Even on tests, like hello.ll, segmentation fault calling `getPointerToFunction` or `runFunctionAsMain`. BTW my IR was generated using clang, so I assume it to be correct.

Comment: @luomoradioattivo: then there's a pretty good chance that your code is wrong. If you were following the `main` of `lli.cpp`, you might have taken something incorrectly or removed too much. I'd suggest you to either carefully compare what differs, or start over from fresh `lli.cpp`. And as a sanity check, make sure that the actual `lli` tool from LLVM 3.3 runs those tests (and your code) successfully.

Answer (score 0):

After running into the same problem as you, I searched through lli.cpp for all non-optional invocations to modules, enginebuilders etc...

I believe what you are missing is a call to "ee->runStaticConstructorDestructors(false)"

Atleast, this fixed the issue for me

Note: This is under llvm3.4, but I have verified that the same instruction also exists in llvm3.1, indicating it propably exists in 3.3 aswell.